# Offline mirror for Firebase

Tags: firebase

We have a client interested in our app, which relies on Firebase. However, they want to use this while they are out to sea and won't be able to connect to the cloud.

They do have a local server and a local wi-fi network.

Does anyone know if using the Firebase Local Emulator Suite would be a practical solution to this problem?

Comment: Do records need to be synced between devices? or in other words will Firestore in offline mode not be a viable option?

Comment: Yea unfortuantely they do.

Comment: damn....Frank is your man on this...

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the response. Yea I guess its as good as it gets so far? Do you think its worth keeping the answer open in case firebase releases a newer update or its just an ideological choice not to offer offline functionality at this point?

Comment: My answer reflects the current status, so I guess that makes it acceptable. If the situation changed, we can either update my existing answer, or post a new answer, which you can then accept instead.

Comment: Yea that seems fair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Emulator Suite is for development, not sure production use. From its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite):

> The Firebase Local Emulator Suite is a set of advanced tools **for developers looking to build and test apps locally**

So it is (currently at least) not suitable for using in the scenario you describe.

What you *can* do is look at the offline mode of the various Firebase products, to see if they fit your needs. I recommend checking the documentation for each, or this handy video that covers all of them: [Firebase offline: What works, what doesn't, and what you need to know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrltP8bOHT0).

Comment: Frank - I was wondering, do you think its possible to use the emulator suite just as a proof of concept?